# Jenkins build fails when user logs off node

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, jenkins

Sometimes, builds done by Jenkins (1.461) will stop at a random spot somewhere in the middle. These builds are manually scripted calls to Visual Studio 2008 SP1's devenv.com for primarily C++ code. Visual Studio emits no error messages; the last message in devenv's log is some random file being built. The Jenkins build fails because of a post-build Windows batch command that relies on some of the build outputs. This happens fairly rarely (roughly 1 in 15 builds). Jenkins's error log shows nothing out of the ordinary around the time the build fails. Surprisingly, it says the build succeeded, even though it shows it as failed everywhere else.

The problem is isolated to Jenkins. The same build script run at a developer's desk has never failed in this way.

The Jenkins nodes are 32-bit Windows XP machines. They all have ample available disk space. Jenkins is configured to only run one job at a time per node. The event logs show no obviously bad things (e.g., Visual Studio crashes) happening at the times when the builds stop.

Does anyone have any ideas of things to look into to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What does Jenkins log say? (http://[jenkins_server]/log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up correlating the random build failures with logoff events on the Jenkins nodes. This lead to this [JVM bug/feature](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=a07bcaf1fa874dffffffff9c37f3e77930740?bug_id=6871190) (Oracle Java bug ID 6871190), where a logoff event in Windows causes the signal handlers to terminate the JVM. You can disable this behavior (perhaps with other downsides) by passing the -Xrs option to the JVM, but that option will not automatically propagate to child Java processes.

We are passing -Xrs to kick off Jenkins itself, and the Jenkins service itself lives through a logoff. The current hypothesis is that some part of Jenkins's build process is kicked off through another Java child process who is not invoked with -Xrs.

Comment: I had the same problem with Matlab which is a java app, I found out that I could set '-Xrs' in its 'java.opts' file.  worth checking if your downstream  process has a java.opts file as it seems  common.

Comment: I'm facing same problem in Ubuntu:- "Sometimes, builds done by Jenkins (1.461) will stop at a random spot somewhere in the middle. The problem is isolated to Jenkins. The same build script run at a developer's desk has never failed in this way"

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall ever having this problem with jenkins myself, but I have regular linker crashes in MSVC 2008. This happens almost everyday for me. If it is the linker crashing then that could be an explanation.(perhaps a linker crash is not logged?)

Edit:
We use MSVC2008 SP1 on 32-bit Win7.
We use MSBuild 3.5 when building the c++ solutions.